# Drupal : Custom access for a web-based custom type

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

For my Drupal site, I maid a custom type named MyCoolCustomType.
I'd like to grant access to view this customtype only to certain condition on user role and properties of the custom content itself (ex. the ModerationState of the content).

I'm quite confused about how to process :

Thank to a class that extends RouteSubscriberBase, I'm trying to modify the route entity.node.canonical to change the "requirements" part. In this part, I'm gonna add a "_custom_access" section in which I will call a dedicated Service.

@Serghei Leonenco, I add the code :

in mymodule.services.yml :

```
  content_moderation.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\content_moderation\Routing\ContentModerationRouteSubscriber
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

mymodule/src/EventSubscriber/SituationProAccessSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\neocadre_features\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;


class SituationProAccessSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase
{
  /**
   * @var AccountProxy
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  public function __construct(AccountProxyInterface $currentUser) {
    $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
  }

  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
        
        // Here it is :) maybe :)
        // Can I filter my content type here ?
      }
  }
}
```

My question is : Where is the good place to filter only MyCoolCustomType ? In the Service, or in the Subscriber ?
By the way, is this the good way to build advanced access check for a custom contentype ?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Any code? What you tried so far? Read how to ask questions. That will helps us to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I add the corresponding code in the original message